# Does ICS have a different XML layout for custom contact sync adapters?

Tags: android, contacts, adapter

I have a custom sync adapter that uses a custom layout in /res/xml/contacts.xml to display some of the contact fields in the stock contacts app. Here is a generic version of the XML:

```
<ContactsSource xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <ContactsDataKind
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/com.test.myapp.TestField1"
            android:summaryColumn="data2"
            android:detailColumn="data3"
            android:detailSocialSummary="false" />
        <ContactsDataKind
            android:icon="@drawable/edit"
            android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/com.test.myapp.editContact"
            android:summaryColumn="data2"
            android:detailColumn="data3"
            android:detailSocialSummary="false" />
    </ContactsSource>
```

And on system running Gingerbread, it works perfectly -- both the summary, data, and icon are displayed in the stock contacts app. But in ICS, they are all lumped in together unde the "Connections" heading. Every custom field is shown, but only it's data, not the summary or the icon. Is there a different layout that I need to use for ICS, or is there anything else I'm missing?